# Change rep stats from "week/month/quarter/year" to "last 7/30/90/365 days" (or add the latter)

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-leagues

I was just perusing the SO leader board, just curious as to who has been doing what in the last month/quarter/year.  However, since we are only four days into the latest month/quarter/year, the stats are all the same.

That means rep leader board history is only truly accurate at the end of the month/quarter/year.  Maybe more "competitive" users care about monthly/quarterly/yearly ladders, but for us "spectators" perhaps a rolling history could be added as well?